# com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to run `com.akexorcist.googledirection` demo [from here](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary)

I am using `Android Studio` and emulator `API version 23`. I haven't modified application at all and it builds and runs ok, however when I click any of buttons on main screen it crashes.

I have tried adding breakpoints in `SimpleDirectionActivity` `onCreate` method, it crashes on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_direction);` line I have checked and `activity_simple_direction.xml` is present in layouts.

`activity_simple_direction.xml` in Layout looks following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SimpleDirectionActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_request_direction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/request_direction" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Full stack trace looks like this:

```
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample, PID: 3806
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample.AlternativeDirectionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample.AlternativeDirectionActivity.onCreate(AlternativeDirectionActivity.java:37)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample.AlternativeDirectionActivity.onCreate(AlternativeDirectionActivity.java:37) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.ao.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
01-20 21:19:56.368 3806-3806/com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample E/AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(Frag
01-20 21:20:00.559 3806-3806/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3806 SIG: 9
```

**Has anyone seen this error before? Why is this failing?**

Comment: Check the permissions the app has - even though `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is requested in the manifest, if you're running on a Marshmallow device you may need to grant this permission yourself (since the app may not be requesting it at runtime).

Details on how to do this here: http://www.greenbot.com/article/2990078/android/how-to-toggle-app-permissions-in-android-marshmallow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` you should get look to this post [gmaps-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021)

In fact you need a SD card in your phone for resolving this issue, for an emulator you can add a SD card directly in the advanced settings.

Hope it helps,

Comment: This did it, much appreciated. Thanks.